# Link HTML hyperlink with server at local disk

Tags: html

I have project in which I'm trying to link to a local file, e.g.

```
<a href="C:\Users\TM******\OneDrive - Xgroup\Pictures\Screenshots>Click to open folder</a>
```

I've tried many methods and am now out of ideas.

I've already tried to change the link that connects to the server but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hello Noor, You are willing to connect localhost with server means how ? Kindly explain more also you mentioned that you tried many methods then please share your code so that we can get more clarity

Comment: A web page can't link to the local file system.

Comment: the files stored on (\\server01\Installer For MS\Noor\01. RFID Application). the localhost I using now is (http://localhost/Master_Application/Dashboard.php). when user click one of the link on webpage localhost, it should be enter the address file server. but it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load files from your local file system in a web page served from a web server due to security reasons. Your localhost doesn't know it is on your file system and likewise your file system doesn't know the address `localhost` is itself, it gets treated as a separate web server.

If you move the file you want to reach into a directory on your localhost, the problem should be resolved.